AWS SAM Deploy Failing with "Resource handler returned message: "Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: N8JK1SK...)"
I'm facing issues while deploying my AWS SAM application. My deployment fails with the following errors:
CREATE_FAILED, AWS::S3::BucketPolicy - "Resource handler returned message: "Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: N8JK1SK...)"
Config in my Template.yaml file:
ImageS3Bucket:
Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
Properties: 
  BucketName: !Sub 'my-public-bucket-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}'

ImageS3BucketPolicy:
Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
Properties:
  Bucket: !Ref ImageS3Bucket
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Sid: PublicReadGetObject
        Effect: Allow
        Principal: '*'
        Action: 
          - 's3:GetObject'
        Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${ImageS3Bucket}/*'

Outputs:
  BucketName:
    Description: 'Image S3 bucket'
    Value: !Ref ImageS3Bucket
  BucketURL:
    Description: 'URL of the S3 bucket'
    Value: !Sub 'https://${ImageS3Bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com'

I've attached the following policy to my IAM admin user (which already had AdministratorAccess when it failed the first time):
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-public-bucket-*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-public-bucket-*/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudformation:CreateStack",
            "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
            "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
            "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
            "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]

}
Questions:
How can I resolve the Access Denied issue for the BucketPolicy?
Additional Information:

I think the SAM CLI is using the correct AWS credentials (which I checked in .aws/credentials - the access key matches the one I see in the IAM user).

I updated SAM CLI to the latest version (1.118.0).


I appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have. Thanks!

Does this answer your question? Access Denied Error when Creating S3 Bucket Policy with CloudFormation
